# Why UITableView can't be reloadData

Tags: xcode, uitableview, tableview

```
 -(void) reload{
        [self.tableViewa reloadData];
    }

    -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [self.tableViewa reloadData];
        [cachedProperties setTags:nil];


        self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =nil;
        self.tabBarController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =nil;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [[cachedProperties getTags] count];
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CheckMarkCellIdentifier = @"CheckMarkCellIdentifier";
        UITableViewCell * cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CheckMarkCellIdentifier] autorelease];

        NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

        if([[[cachedProperties getTags] objectAtIndex:row] isNotEmpty]){
            cell.textLabel.text = [[cachedProperties getTags]objectAtIndex:row];
            cell.accessoryType= UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        }
        return cell;
    }
```

with this Method, when the viewWillAppear there is a code [self.tableviewa reloadData] and will call numberOfRowsInSection, but when I call method Reload that have [self.tableviewa reloadData] the function numberOfRowInSection won't be called.. how can it be? any reason for this problem?

because in firstTime viewWillAppear called, [cachedProperties setTags:nil] will set tags and will call `-(void) reload{
        [self.tableViewa reloadData];
    }` or [thatClass.tableViewa reloadData] that I need to make tableView is not null. why does tableView not reloadData?

Comment: What about the `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` method? Have you checked that it returns a value other than `0`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 -(void) reload{
        [self.tableViewa reloadData];
        [cachedProperties setTags:nil];
    }

    -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [self reload];

        self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =nil;
        self.tabBarController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =nil;
    }
```

...